# C array: setting element at offset

Tags: c, arrays, offset

I have a 2D array declared as

```
static bool array[ROW][COL];
```

Instead of using the indices, for a particular function I want to use a byte offset to set some of the elements, since the bools in this array are pretty much guaranteed to be 1 byte each.

```
loff_t *offset = 0;
```

So I try the following line.

```
array + *offset = false;
```

However, it compiles with the warning "lvalue required as left operand of assignment". What's wrong with this implementation, and how can I set the element of an array based on byte offset?

Comment: Side note: what makes you so sure that "the bools in this array are pretty much guaranteed to be 1 byte each"??? BTW, either they're 1 byte each or not; "pretty much guaranteed" seems kinda unrealistic statement in this context.

Comment: unless the underlying architecture has bit registers, a `bool` is (almost) always the size of an `int`.

Comment: this line: `loff_t *offset = 0;` is the same as `loff_t *offset = NULL;`  The C language does not allow adding two pointers Suggest: `int offset = 0; array + offset = false;`, those second statement is the same as: `array[0][offset] = false;`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specifying byte offset directly by messing around with pointers while trying to avoid undefined behavior, you could just manually compute the indices for a specific offset:

```
array[offset / COL][offset % COL] = ...
```

---

Above will work only if `sizeof (bool) == sizeof (char)`.

If your program already makes such assumption, you should add following:

```
static_assert(sizeof (bool) == sizeof (char), "sizeof bool != sizeof char");
```

If not, you should use different (pointer based) approach.

Comment: That's a good idea. You can get both indices just by dividing and modding by COL?

Comment: It depends on what the OP needs. If the task specifically calls fo *byte offset*, then no. This approach is: 1. A major obfuscation of the original intent, 2. Not a byte-offset access at all. This approach performs bool-offset access, not byte-offset one.

Comment: I wonder what compiler is able to compile this to a simple addition, which would be equivalent if `offset` (or `COL`) has an unsigned type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an offset into the 2D array as if it were a 1D array, but it is not strictly correct as you are indexing beyond the subarray boundary:

```
*(array[0] + *offset) = false;         // not strictly correct
```

For this syntax, `offset` must contain a number of `bool` types, computed like this:

```
*offset = &array[row][col] - array[0];
```

or equivalently: `*offset = &array[row][col] - &array[0][0];`

An alternative is to alias with a character type, but `bool` might be larger than `char`, so this would be incorrect too:

```
*((char*)array + *offset) = false;  // potentially incorrect
```

To handle the case of `bool` larger than `char`, we may use:

```
*(bool *)((char*)array + *offset) = false;  // quite ugly
```

And `offset` should be computed this way:

```
*offset = (char*)&array[row][col] - (char*)array;
```

Comment: @2501: yes, undefined behavior. Would `*((char*)array[0] + *offset) = false;` be defined and correct?

Comment: Well no, since bool might not be a single byte. Strictly reading the standard, it could be out of bounds too.

Comment: While it will work, it is not entirely clear why you do `array[0]` before casting to `char *`. There's absolutely no need to do `[0]`.

Comment: @AnT: There is no need for the `[0]` indeed, but I do like to keep the same level of indirection when I apply a cast: `array[0]` decays to `bool *`.

Comment: @chqrlie: Same level of indirection? But `array` itself decays to `bool (*)[COL]`. This is also the same level of indirection (i.e. just one level). Explicit array types in C do not intoduce extra levels of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `bool` value stored in the array `array` at byte offset `*offset` will look as follows

```
*(bool *) ((char *) array + *offset) = true;
```

Of course, you will have to assume all risks that follow from this kind of access, since technques like this can easily run afoul of strict-aliasing rules. A safer alternative might be

```
bool new_value = true;
memcpy((char *) array + *offset, &new_value, sizeof new_value);
```